# MapReduce output not the complete set expected?

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, streaming, lzo

I'm running a streaming hadoop job on a single hadoop pseudo-distributed node in python, also using hadoop-lzo to produce splits on a .lzo compressed input file.

Everything works as expected when using small compressed or uncompressed test datasets; MapReduce output matches that from a simple   'cat | map | sort | reduce'  pipeline in unix. - whether the input is compressed or not.

However, once I move to processing the single large .lzo (pre-indexed) dataset (~40GB compressed) and the job is split to multiple mappers, the output looks to be truncated - only the first few key values are present.

The code + outputs follow - as you can see, it's a very simple count for testing the whole process.

output from straight forward unix pipeline on test data (subset of large dataset);

```
lzop -cd objectdata_input.lzo | ./objectdata_map.py | sort | ./objectdata_red.py

3656  3
3671  3
51    6
```

output from hadoop job on test data (same test data as above)

```
hadoop jar $HADOOP_INSTALL/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-*.jar -input objectdata_input.lzo -inputformat com.hadoop.mapred.DeprecatedLzoTextInputFormat -output retention_counts -mapper objectdata_map.py -reducer objectdata_red.py -file /home/bob/python-dev/objectdata_map.py -file /home/bob/python-dev/objectdata_red.py

3656  3
3671  3
51    6
```

Now, the test data is a small subset of lines from the real dataset, so I would at least expect to see the keys from above in the resulting output when the job is run against the full dataset. However, what I get is;

```
hadoop jar $HADOOP_INSTALL/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-*.jar -input objectdata_input_full.lzo -inputformat com.hadoop.mapred.DeprecatedLzoTextInputFormat -output retention_counts -mapper objectdata_map.py -reducer objectdata_red.py -file /home/bob/python-dev/objectdata_map.py -file /home/bob/python-dev/objectdata_red.py

1       40475582
12      48874
14      8929777
15      219984
16      161340
17      793211
18      78862
19      47561
2       14279960
20      56399
21      3360
22      944639
23      1384073
24      956886
25      9667
26      51542
27      2796
28      336767
29      840
3       3874316
30      1776
33      1448
34      12144
35      1872
36      1919
37      2035
38      291
39      422
4       539750
40      1820
41      1627
42      97678
43      67581
44      11009
45      938
46      849
47      375
48      876
49      671
5       262848
50      5674
51      90
6       6459687
7       4711612
8       20505097
9       135592
```

...There are many less keys than I would expect based on the dataset.

I'm less bothered by the key's themselves - this set could be expected given the input dataset, I am more concerned that there should be many many more keys, in the thousands. When I run the code in a unix pipeline against the first 25million records in the dataset,  I get keys in the range approx 1 - 7000.

So, this output appears to be just the first few lines of what I would actually expect, and I'm not sure why. Am I missing collating many part-0000# files? or something similar? this is just a single-node pseudo-distributed hadoop I am testing on at home, so if there are more part-# files to collect I have no idea where they could be; they do not show up in the retention_counts dir in HDFS.

The mapper and reducer code is as follows - effectivley the same as the many word-count examples floating about;

objectdata_map.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
RETENTION_DAYS=(8321, 8335)

for line in sys.stdin:
        line=line.strip()
        try:
                retention_days=int(line[RETENTION_DAYS[0]:RETENTION_DAYS[1]])
                print "%s\t%s" % (retention_days,1)
        except:
                continue
```

objectdata_red.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python                                                                                                                                    

import sys                                                                                                                                               
last_key=None
key_count=0
for line in sys.stdin:
        key=line.split('\t')[0]
        if last_key and last_key!=key:
                print "%s\t%s" % (last_key,key_count)
                key_count=1
        else:
                key_count+=1

        last_key=key

print "%s\t%s" % (last_key,key_count)
```

This is all on a manually installed hadoop 1.1.2, pseudo-distributed mode, with hadoop-lzo built and installed from

https://github.com/kevinweil/hadoop-lzo

Comment: You appear to be silently swallowing exceptions in your mapper - this could be you problem - try printing the error on stderr and then checking the logs for a map task to see what the error if any is

Comment: good point; this was just to skip cases where the int() conversion failed but I shall investigate further.